# add hover to a link within a section that effects every element but the one hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

## SOLVED BY OLIVER

(https://stackoverflow.com/users/20025773/oliver) in the comments of his response. Thank you for your help and continued iterations of solutions and explanation!

...

Original Post:

I'm trying to find a way to add a hover effect to a link within a section that, when hovered, affects all other content within the section. For example, reducing the opacity to 0.2.

The one caveat is that I will need to retain the ability to ALSO add specific hover effects to the link hovered, for example adding a background color (use blue as an example) that maintain the original solution.

Here is an example of the layout I'm trying to use.
HTML:

```
      <ul id="text">

        <li>
          <a href="#">Whole line link</a>,
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Part line link</a>, and
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">Link split over <br />
        Two lines</a>.
      </li>

        <li>
          Here's another <a href="#">Part line link,<br />
        Split </a>, again over two lines.
      </li>
 
      </ul>
```

So, in summary, if I hover any of these links, I want the opacity of everything outside of the hovered anchor tag to drop to 0.2, and I want only the hovered anchor tag to get a background color.
TYIA :-)

I have tried using has and not selectors however these are a bit past my current level of comprehension and are new to me. I'm open to whatever solutions are possible. I took similar code from a similar tutorial and from similar stackoverflow questions  and couldn't make that element work for my specific case, however even without fixing the initial problem it seemed like this solution would run into problems with the second part of my problem - retaining the ability to style everything BUT the hovered link (turning all others to opacity 0.2) while letting me style only the hovered link (setting the background color to blue)

...

UPDATES after some answers and attempts at resolving -- big issues seem to be:

- current compatibility in firefox for the has selector, even if the flag is enabled. working fine in chrome.
- having the hover only on the `<a>` tag link text
- having the opacity drop on all elements in the `<ul>` and not just the `<a>` tag link texts of the `<ul>`
- having the opacity drop for ALL elements outside of the hovered `<a>` tag link text, including other non link text within the same `<li>` as the hovered link text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
ul:has(li a:hover) > li a:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

You essentially say: If the `ul` has any `a` that is inside any `li` that are hovered, any `a` that is inside any `li` that is `not` hovered should have opacity: 0.2

Hope it makes sens!

here is a code pen: https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/OJovqGd

Comment: the only problem is this keeps the entire content within the `<li>` at full opacity when hovered, this is most noticeable on the final line of the example in your codepen.

I've also found out this is entirely not working for me in firefox which might have made my initial attempts even harder for me. for whatever reason even on the codepen I have to open in it chrome to make it work for me.

Comment: I understood your question wrong. And yes, unfortunately, Firefox does not support `:has` yet. https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas

Also, you can achieve the effect that you described using `:has` but you are limited in some ways because if you add a style on the `li` the `a` will be affected as well simply by being a child. You can lower the opacity of the `li` using the a color with an alpha value, for ex using `rgba` or `hext` while still having control over the `a` hover effect.

Here is a new codepen: https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/MWqVREp

Comment: that codepen is quite close actually, i would just need a way to make it apply to all the other elements in the `<ul>` but from what I can tell it handles the entire `<li>` content exactly how I need

Comment: All the `li`'s except the `a`s? Or with the `a`' except the hovered one?

Comment: Is this https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/MWqVREp what you are looking for? I've noticed that if you add the extra text inside a `span` you have more flexibility over the effect without affecting the `a` tag. Notice that I used `opacity` inserted a a color with an alpha value

Comment: latest codepen is working almost exactly. it just doesn't impact the opacity of the other `<a>` tags other than the one hovered. now that I know about the firefox issue this is where I got up to myself re running the old code I thought was completely broken in chrome (so that's nice to know I figured some of it out myself). Just can't figure out how to allow the non hovered links to drop opacity as well as the plain span text

Comment: just read your updated question and I have updated the codepen as well. Take a look: https://codepen.io/raul-rogojan/pen/MWqVREp

Comment: It seems that last one works perfectly. Could you please explain it though? Thank you for your help here it's been greatly appreciated I've been stuck on this for a while. (i think i've mostly figured it out on my own)

Comment: `ul:has(li a:hover) span` Sounds like this does: the `ul` `has` any `a` selected with `li a` that are hovered? then all `span` should have opacity `0.2`. You can add a class on the `a` and `span` and replace them in the selectors and should work fine. for example `.navList:has(.link:hover) .extraText`. `ul:has(li a:hover) a:not(:hover)` this is also saying if `ul` `has` any `a` inside that are hovered all the `a` that are `not` `(:hovered)` should have opacity 0.2. This `ul:has(li a:hover) span, ul:has(li a:hover) a:not(:hover)` is literally the equivalent of `.elementX:hover, elementY:hover`